# Is it possible to load plugin from console with core ?

Tags: plugin-development, cron

I developing some scrapping plugin for my own purpose. So each 10 minutes i need to start my plugin from the cron. Plugin will parse some posts from other pages and add it to wp. So is it possible to load plugin with wp core from console?

Answer (score 1):

While the idea that you are "developing some scrapping plugin" is sketchy and off-putting, the general question is "How do I fire code using system cron jobs?" and that is a valid question.

You don't need to jump through hoops to load WordPress. Set up an [AJAX API callback](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)...

```
function fire_cron_job_wpse_144051() {
  // fire your code
  die();
}
// add_action('wp_ajax_fire_cron', 'fire_cron_job_wpse_14405');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_fire_cron', 'fire_cron_job_wpse_14405');
```

... and have your system cron job make a request to `//example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=fire_cron`. Note that `fire_cron` is the trailing part of the two action hooks. You can set that to whatever you like.

Answer (score -1):

You can load Wordpress core anywhere.

require_once('/../../../wp-blog-header.php'); // Use actual root path to wp-blog-header.php
header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");

Here is a discussion.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101503/include-wordpress-core-into-own-scripts

Comment: ok, and how then load plugin?

Comment: If you wanted to run a plugin from the command line Id try http://wp-cli.org/commands/eval-file/. It loads Wordpress then your file.