# Is it OK to use a system cron to trigger a function hooked into the AJAX API

Tags: ajax, wp-cron

I have a real cron job setup and it seems to work. I have outlined the basics below.

The reason I ask is I don't see this method mentioned often and I'm wondering if that is because doing so is a bad idea?

I don't want to use `wp-cron` and disabling `wp-cron` on my site causes problems in other places (* even while using a real cron to run `/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron`)

**Below is an example of what I'm doing:**

**Function**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_function', 'my_function');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_function', 'my_function' );
my_function() {
 ...stuff
}
```

**Url**
`wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_function`

**Cron**
`*/45 12-23 * * * wget http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_function > /dev/null`

Comment: If you have system `cron` job setup, why do you need to run it with an ajax call at all?

Comment: Basically I want a way to easily use a function, from a theme or plugin, with a cron job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the system `cron` to trigger a function hooked into the AJAX API, not, as your title reads, using "`admin-ajax.php` to run a real `cron` job". You are doing exactly the opposite of what you wrote in the title (I'd advise editing that).

Yes, that is perfectly fine. I have [advised using the same technique](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/144064/21376) in fact. All you are doing is making a request to the server on an accurately timed schedule, instead of waiting for a random request from the web. It is no different from any other request to the server.